Eslint show only one error in Neovim, enen though there are multiple errors in the buffer
When using Eslint in Neovim, (either the Eslint LSP or eslint_d) when I have multiple errors in the buffer, I only get ONE error, the very first one in the buffer. All the other errors are not markers lower in the buffer. I am not sure if this is a config error? I tried all sorts of things, but to no avail.
Here is how my eslint.config.mjs file looks like:
import globals from "globals";
import pluginJs from "@eslint/js";
import pluginVue from "eslint-plugin-vue";


export default [
  {files: ["**/*.{js,mjs,cjs,vue}"]},
  { languageOptions: {
      globals: {
        _: 'readonly',
        $: 'readonly',
        ...globals.browser,
      }
    }
  },
  pluginJs.configs.recommended,
  ...pluginVue.configs["flat/essential"],
  {
    rules: {
      'vue/no-unused-vars': 'off',
      'indent': 'off',
      'linebreak-style': ['error', 'unix'],
      'quotes': 'off',
      'semi': 'off',
    }
  }
];

It is a very simple one. I am not sure if I am missing something here maybe?
Here is my LSP config with neovim/nvim-lspconfig:
["eslint"] = function()
        -- configure eslint server
        lspconfig["eslint"].setup({
          -- ESLint server configuration
          filetypes = { "javascript", "javascriptreact", "typescript", "typescriptreact", "vue" },
          settings = {
            codeAction = {
              disableRuleComment = {
                enable = true,
                location = "separateLine"
              },
              showDocumentation = {
                enable = true
              }
            },
            format = true,
            codeActionOnSave = {
              enable = false,
              mode = 'all',  -- Apply all fixes on save
            },
            run = "onType",
            validate = "on",
          },
          root_dir = lspconfig.util.root_pattern(
            'eslint.config.js',
            'eslint.config.mjs',
            '.eslintrc',
            '.eslintrc.js',
            '.eslintrc.cjs',
            '.eslintrc.yaml',
            '.eslintrc.yml',
            '.eslintrc.json'
          ),
          -- Format a document on save
          on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
            vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd("BufWritePre", {
              buffer = bufnr,
              command = "EslintFixAll",
            })
          end,
        })
      end,

Any help is GREATLY appriciated. Thanks!


Could you share a very simple version of your script with: 1 the first error 2. The other errors you would like to see hlighted?

I suspect that the first error ruins the possibility for the parser to understand the rest of the script and to identify the next errors.
If the first error is a syntax error the behavior you have could be normal.

That can't be it, because if I open the same file in SublimeText which also uses Eslint, Sublime shows all the errors in that file.

Good argument! But in order to help you it would be helpful to be able reproduce your issue. For that an example would help.

Hmmmm, I am not sure what kind of an example to give you so you can reproduce it. It does it for literally any Javascript file with the above config.

I think that it was an Eslint error. After update, it works fine now. Thanks for the help.

Thanks for the feedback :-)
